# Accessing Properties.Resources from SharePoint ASPX page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

This might be a pretty silly question, but I'm new to `ASP.NET` and I'm not able to pull values from `myProject.Properties.Resources` within the ASPX-page itself.

I've tried the below but the page fails to load

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources: Resources, string1 %>">
```

If it makes any difference, this page is a part of a `SharePoint` project and the page is in `myProject/ADMIN/myProject/mypage.aspx`

Any help here would be really appreciated

Comment: Seems to be the good syntax.
Have you tried to define the text with resources in code behind ?

Comment: @ThibaultGandon yes, and that works fine (Label1.Text = Properties.Resources.String1)